# Combining two Arrays of hashes based on a hash key

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays of variable lengths: `people1` and `people2`. I want to create an array of arrays where each inner array is a pair of elements from `people1` and `people2` The pairing should be based on a matching key. I'm using Ruby 2.2.0.

For example, given this input:

```
people1 = [{ name: :jon, id: 1 }, { name: :jay, id: 3 }, { name: :ray, id: 5 }]
people2 = [{ name: :jon, id: 2 }, { name: :ray, id: 7 }]
```

I would like this result:

```
pairs = [
  [{ name: :jon, id: 1 }, { name: :jon, id: 2 }],
  [{ name: :ray, id: 5 }, { name: :ray, id: 7 }]
]
```

Here's what I came up with:

```
people1.collect do |p1|
  if p2 = people2.find { |p2| p1[:name] == p2[:name] }
    [p1, p2]
  else
    nil
  end
end.compact
```

I looked at Array#zip, but it doesn't seem to take a condition. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

First create a hash that maps names to the hashes for one list:

```
people2_by_name = Hash[people2.map { |h| [h[:name], h] }]
```

Filter the other list

```
people1.select { |h| people2_by_name.has_key?(h[:name]) }
       .map { |h| [h, people2_by_name[h[:name]]] }
```

This will only work properly if there are no duplicate names in each, but it is \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ in the number of hashes.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know Ruby.

Comment: It's correct, nevertheless :)

Answer (score 4):

Veedrac's answer will certainly work - this is just to present an alternative.

Namely, you could combine the arrays and use `#group_by`:

```
(people1 + people2)
  .group_by { |person| person[:name] }
  .map { |name, people| people if people.count > 1 }
  .compact
```

Or, instead of `compact`ing `nil` values, you could do:

```
(people1 + people2)
  .group_by { |person| person[:name] }
  .map(&:last)
  .select { |people| people.count > 1 }
```

Same result.

Answer (score 2):

I have assumed that, in both `people1` and `people2`, the values of `:name` are unique.

Here's one way to extract the desired pairs.

**Code**

```
def extract_pairs(people1, people2)
  h2 = people2.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[:name]=>g) }
  people1.each_with_object([]) do |g,a|
    k = g[:name]
    a << [g,h2[k]] if h2.key?(k)
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
people1 = [{ name: :jon, id: 1 }, { name: :jay, id: 3 }, { name: :ray, id: 5 }]
people2 = [{ name: :jon, id: 2 }, { name: :ray, id: 7 }]
extract_pairs(people1, people2)
  #=> [[{:name=>:jon, :id=>1}, {:name=>:jon, :id=>2}],
  #    [{:name=>:ray, :id=>5}, {:name=>:ray, :id=>7}]]
```

**Explanation**

For the above example:

```
enum0 = people2.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{:name=>:jon, :id=>2}, {:name=>:ray, :id=>7}]:
  #     each_with_object({})> 

g, h2 = enum0.next
  #=> [{:name=>:jon, :id=>2}, {}] 
g #=> {:name=>:jon, :id=>2} 
h2 #=> {} 
h2.update(g[:name]=>g)
  #=> {}.update(:jon=>{:name=>:jon, :id=>2})
  #=> {:jon=>{:name=>:jon, :id=>2}} 

g, h2 = enum0.next
  #=> [{:name=>:ray, :id=>7}, {:jon=>{:name=>:jon, :id=>2}}] 
h2.update(g[:name]=>g)
  #=> {:jon=>{:name=>:jon, :id=>2}}.update(:ray=>{:name=>:ray, :id=>7}
  #=> {:jon=>{:name=>:jon, :id=>2}, :ray=>{:name=>:ray, :id=>7}}
```

```
enum1 = people1.each_with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: [{:name=>:jon, :id=>1}, {:name=>:jay, :id=>3},
  #     {:name=>:ray, :id=>5}]:each_with_object([])> 

g, a = enum1.next
  #=> [{:name=>:jon, :id=>1}, []] 
k = g[:name]
  #=> :jon 
a << [g,h2[k]] if h2.key?(k)
  # [] << [{:name=>:jon, :id=>1},
  #   {:jon=>{:name=>:jon, :id=>2}, :ray=>{:name=>:ray, :id=>7}}[:jon] if
  #   {:jon=>{:name=>:jon, :id=>2}, :ray=>{:name=>:ray, :id=>7}}.key?(:jon)
  # [] << [{:name=>:jon, :id=>1}, {:name=>:jon, :id=>2}] if true
a #=> [{:name=>:jon, :id=>1}, {:name=>:jon, :id=>2}]

g, a = enum1.next
  #=> [{:name=>:jay, :id=>3},
  #    [[{:name=>:jon, :id=>1}, {:name=>:jon, :id=>2}]]] 
k = g[:name]
  #=> :jay 
a << [g,h2[k]] if h2.key?(k)
  #=> nil

g, a = enum1.next
  #=> [{:name=>:ray, :id=>5},
  #    [[{:name=>:jon, :id=>1}, {:name=>:jon, :id=>2}]]] 
k = g[:name]
  #=> :ray 
a << [g,h2[k]] if h2.key?(k)
  #=> [[{:name=>:jon, :id=>1}, {:name=>:jon, :id=>2}],
  #    [{:name=>:ray, :id=>5}, {:name=>:ray, :id=>7}]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one liner similar to Flambinos, but in my version, rather than mapping, producing unwanted nils, then compacting them, you are simply selecting the elements that you want. The intent is more transparent. It also allows you to use blocks with one argument only. These are subtle benefits, to be sure, and I like Flambino's solution, but I thought the improvement was worth posting

```
(people1 + people2).group_by {|x| x[:name]}.values.select {|x| x.size > 1}
```